# Conditionals in python classes

Tags: python, class

I am actually working on a project and I want to insert a conditional in a get method on a class. This conditional has to take as argument the last sentence and evaluate if that sentence returns something or not. Here is a foo code of what I want to do:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,mylist):
        self.array=mylist
    def first_item(self):
        z=mylist[0]
        if z==0:
            return z
        else:
            print("First item is not 0")
a=foo([0,2])
b=foo(1)

print(a.first_item)
print(b.first_item)
```

The main objective is to evaluate if z has any value or not.

Thank you so much.

Comment: It’s not clear what the problem is. Can you provide an example where what you have now does not work as you expect?

Comment: `mylist` is a local variable in `__init__`; you want `self.mylist` in the other method.

Comment: What are you referring to as the last sentence and what do you mean by "..determine if that sencence returns something..."? Could you update your question with a written example of a possible input and the expected output?

Comment: You also have to *call* the method; `print(a.first_item())`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, mylist):
        self.array = mylist

    def first_item(self, should_be=0):
        if len(self.array) > 0:  # inserted list can be empty
            first = self.array[0]
            if first == should_be:
               print(first)
            else:
                print(f"First item is not {should_be}")
        else:
            print("empty list")
a = Foo([0,2])
b = Foo([1])
c = Foo([])
d = Foo([2,3])

a.first_item() # 0
b.first_item() # "First item is not 0"
c.first_item(4) # empty list
d.first_item(2) # 2
```

**Some important things to notice:**

1. Should always pass a list to the input. Otherwise it will behave strange (try pass a dict and check.. )
2. Should always check for empty input.
3. If you don't pass the first item you expect, the default is zero `0`. Which means if your list is of strings: `['a', 'b', 'c']`, you'll compare `'a' == 0`, which is also strange..

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

there are several issues with you your code

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self,mylist):
        self.array=mylist
        if type(self.array) is not list: #  make it a list if it isnt
            self.array = [self.array]
    def first_item(self):
        z=self.array[0] #  use your class variable, mylist doesnt exist here
        if z==0:
            return z
        else:
            return "First item is not 0" #  it is not clear if you want to return this value, raise an error or just print and return nothing

a=foo([0,2])
b=foo(1)

print(a.first_item()) #  the () are important, otherwise you arent calling the function
print(b.first_item())
```

will print :
0
First item is not 0

Comment: You are right, sorry for all those issues, wrote this dumb code quickly and maybe it was not the best example.